# findViewById with getIdentifier not working

Tags: java, android, view, casting, spinner

I'm looping through an array, in that for-loop I'm also using this array to get IDs for a couple of spinners:

```
Integer[] ids;
ids = new Integer[8];
ids[0] = R.id.nr_area;
ids[1] = R.id.nr_municipality;
ids[2] = R.id.nr_method;
ids[3] = R.id.nr_bait;
ids[4] = R.id.nr_sessionhours;
ids[5] = R.id.nr_bifangst_art;
ids[6] = R.id.nr_bifangst_released;
ids[7] = R.id.nr_name;
```

In the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
if(fields[i].contains("*") || fields[i].matches("")){

 String test = ids[i].toString();
 int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(test, "id", getPackageName());

 Spinner spnr = (Spinner) findViewById(resID); //error is on this row
 spnr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
 }
}
```

Now the error I get is as follows:

```
android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
```

So I guess this can't be used with a spinner as I found the example code for a EditText.. but how can I do what I'm trying to do with a spinner?

I would appreciate any help! Been fighting with this for hours. Thanks alot..

Comment: One of those ids must be an `EditText` which appcompat changes to its own custom `EditText` for tinting. I don't understand the need for using getIdentifier.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense - looping based on some `fields` array but pulling from `ids` based on the same index. Which of the ids are identifying the "couple of spinners"?

Comment: @JaredRummler you were right, one of the IDs wasn't a spinner but an EditText. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks alot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that either one of the ids is of EditText or id was of EditText and you have changed it to Spinner in your xml lately. Make sure that ids are correct, relate them from xml, if still problem persists, try cleaning your project for indexing again, that should do it.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: You were totaly right! One of the IDs actually was an EditText hence the error.. sorry! And thanks alot :)